# S3 access to only one IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I set the S3 read permission to only my IAM User can access? I have my IAM User config in the backend for my hybrid app but I still can't get access to S3 list.

Here is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/xxx@xxx.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried `was s3 ls s3://my-s3-bucket` on terminal it is showing the list of items in my s3 bucket but not the backend. If I change the Principal to "*" I can access without any problem. (I want to limit to only my app can access it with the IAM User credential I have).

The error I have

> {"code":"InternalError","message":"Access Denied"}

Thank you.

Comment: Probably better to ensure that all IAM users *except* this one are members of an IAM group that has a Deny policy on the S3 bucket. That would, to my mind, be safer than adding a Deny policy to the S3 bucket itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws s3 ls` command is used to **list the contents of a bucket** but your policy is only granting permission to `GetObject` (which means to read the contents of an object).

If you wish to allow *listing* of the bucket, you would also need to grant `s3:ListBucket` permissions.

**Bucket Policies vs IAM Policies**

Typically, Bucket Policies are used to grant public or cross-account access.

If you wish to grant access to a specific IAM User, then it is better to **add a policy on the IAM User themselves**:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, you say "***only*** one user". This becomes more difficult if any other users have been granted access to *ALL* S3 buckets with an Admin-like policy. In this situation, it you would need to add a `Deny` to the Bucket Policy to prevent access by anyone who has been granted access to all Buckets. This starts to get a little tricky because Deny policies have a habit of denying more than you expect.

If the bucket contains **sensitive information**, another option is to **put the bucket in a different AWS Account** and then only grant cross-account access to the specific IAM Users who need access. This prevents people gaining Admin-like access and avoids the need to use a Deny policy.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I only want to allow my account to have the read access to download the pdf file in s3 bucket. When I said "only one" I meant just my AWS Account (as I only have one IAM User). I'm not sure if it will work, what if the person that is using the app and give someone else the pdf file url? Will they be able to see the file as well(not open directly from the app)? I hope I'm not making it too confusing. Thanks!

Comment: All objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. You can give your IAM User **Admin** permissions and it will have access to do whatever you want within your account. There is **no need to create a Bucket Policy**. Please note that you will need to identify yourself when accessing the object, so you will need to access the file via the S3 management console, or by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Comment: Thanks, other than access the file via S3 console or using AWS-CLI can the server side do the same thing? I tried the code you provide before in my IAM User inline policy but the server side still can't access the pdf file in s3. I have to go into the s3 console to enable "read" for the object one by one.

Comment: It sounds like your "server side" is accessing the object via an HTTP/S request? If you are doing it this way, your code can generate a [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which grants temporary access to a private object. The preference is to have your code use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to call Amazon S3 directly and download the file (with authentication).

Comment: Yes, the project is accessing the object via an https request and allow user to tap the pdf button to open the browser to view/export the pdf. Does it also work for the "s3:PutObject" to sync the bluetooth device and upload new pdf file to s3 bucket? I'm not sure if the server side is using IAM instance profile or IAM User (I only see the credential part including the access key, secret access key, region and bucket name) What happen after the url expire? Will aws produce a new url? Sorry I'm pretty new to this. Thank you.

Comment: Once the pre-signed URL expires, it will no longer function. The application can always generate another one, but it needs to know the Access Key and Secret Key that is permitted to access the object. They are used to generate the URL. A pre-signed URL can also be used to upload objects: [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

For `s3 ls s3://my-s3-bucket` to work you need `s3:ListBucket` permissions along with bucket resource:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/xxx@xxx.com"
            },
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*", 
                          "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket"]
        }
    ]
}
```